# How do I invite friends along the salvage droids?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star, android

The tutorial states, that I can bring along friends to get better results with my free salvage droid. How do I add them? Sending the "?" bitizens on this level does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Salvage Droids level, and then click the "Get More" button next to the first "Launch for 5" button.  It will randomly poll your FB friends and you can check/uncheck the ones you want to invite as you want.